# Javascript checking if textbox filled or checkbox checked and displaying a div

Tags: javascript, html, text, checkbox, show

I have a button like this:

```
input type="submit" name="continue" id="continue" value="CONTINUE" class="submitContact" />
```

Then for this button I am setting up a js that looks like this:

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
    $('#storePickUp').change(function() { //catch checkbox
        var $check = $(this),
        $div = $check.parent();
    if($check.prop('checked') || $('#shippingZipCode').val().length) 
    {
    $('.checkoutForm').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
document.getElementById(shippingZipCode).style.backgroundColor = '#FFFEAD'; 
    }
  });

});
```

What I try to do is check whether a textbox `.shippingZipCode`is filled out or a checkbox is checked `#storePickUp`, and if affirmative I display a div that has class `.checkoutForm`.

However, I cannot get it to work. Does this js look ok?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens, exactly? Any error messages in console? Page reloads? (using submit button usually leads to this)

Comment: I think you will get error at document.getElementById(shippingZipCode) .Try $('#shippingZipCode')

Comment: `document.getElementById(shippingZipCode)` is missing ' ' for the id : `document.getElementById('shippingZipCode')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event is coming from a `submit` typed input. So first things first, you must `return false` to prevent it from posting and redirecting.

Secondly, your click event is only assigning a change event. The change event will issue its assigned callback when a change is made to the selected input, which may not be for some time, definitely shorted than the few milliseconds before the page posts.

You are going to want to check for your values, then decide which action to take, and then return false in order to stop the post from happening.

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
  var $check = $('#storePickUp');//use reference to check for value immediately
  var $div = $check.parent();
  if($check.prop('checked') || $('#shippingZipCode').val().length) 
  {
   $('.checkoutForm').fadeIn(1000);
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById('shippingZipCode').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFEAD'; 
  }
  return false;//prevent form from posting
});
```

Comment: Thanks but not working. My submit input is not within <form> tags, would that matter?

Comment: @samyb8 - If it is not contained in a form, then you will not need to `return false` because there is no form to submit. Aside from that, which part is not working? Be specific please :)

Comment: @samyb8 - It works fine for me (note that you forgot to include jquery). See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Et7B7/2/

Answer (score 0):

No need for the change function for the checkbox. Just check its state.

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
    var $check = $('#storePickUp'),
    $div = $check.parent();

    if($check.prop('checked') || $('#shippingZipCode').val().length) {
        $('.checkoutForm').fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('shippingZipCode').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFEAD';
    }
});
```